# Does a producer make two different connections to broker and Schema registry? If yes, Is it a HTTP connection?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I'm using spring-kafka-2.2.7.RELEASE and have a producer and consumer. My cluster has zookeepers, brokers and a shema registry as well to handle the avro schema validation. So, in my producer configuration, I'll pass in both brokers URL and Schema Registry URL. Now I've couple of questions,

1. when publishing/producing a message, Does the producer make two different connections to broker and schema registry or just one connection to broker and from there broker would communicate with schema registry?
2. If it opens only one connection, how long does the connection would be open? Can the producer use the same connection to produce multiple messages or should it open multiple connections to produce multiple messages?
3. If there is a connection open, does it use HTTP/HTTPS protocol to communicate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The schema registry has nothing to do with Kafka; there is a separate HTTP connection made directly from the client.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the clarification. I've another question here. Would the producer make multiple calls to schema registry if it is producing multiple messages?

Comment: You shouldn't ask follow-up questions in comments. It looks to me that the serializer will make one call for each schema and cache the ids locally to avoid calling each time.